# Turn MIDI control input into virtual keystrokes (or virtual USB buttons etc) on macOS

Tags: macos, blender, midi

I would like to use MIDI control devices (like this https://www.korg.com/us/products/computergear/nanokontrol2/ ) to generate control input for various software, Blender in particular.

One way is obviously to add MIDI input handling into Blender. Adding low-level code to Blender to listen for MIDI buttons and sliders is not hard at all, and I have basically implemented that. (I.e. I added a new "class" of input, MIDI, at Blender's lowest level.) But connecting that to the existing keyboard and mouse plumbing and especially UI functionality to associate functions with input is much more complex, and not something I want to dive into now.

Another way would perhaps be to instead run some separate software that listens for MIDI events and turns those into virtual keystrokes. Assuming it is possible to generate a much larger variety of keystrokes than there are actual keys on any keyboard, this could work nicely (like, generate keystrokes corresponding to various Unicode blocks that no real keyboard ever has). Does this sound feasible? Is a11y APIs what I should be looking at to implement such virtual keystroke generation? This way would have the benefit that it would work with any software.

Or does anybody have some better idea?

Comment: (Even though the title says macOS, obviously such a thing would be needed for all three major platforms. macOS just happens to be the platform that I run Blender on. If I ever get to actually work on implementing this, I would do it for all three platforms.)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I wrote this small program. Works beautifully (once you give it the right to generate key events in *System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility > Allow the apps below to control your computer*). MIDI note on and off events and MIDI controller value changes generate macOS key presses of keys with CJK Unified Ideographs as the characters.

But, then I see that Blender is the kind of software that thinks that ASCII should be enough for everybody. In other words, Blender has hardcoded restrictions that the only keys it handles are basically those on an English keyboard. You can't bind even Cyrillic or Greek keys (for which there after all exists actual keyboards) to Blender functions, much less CJK keys. Sigh. Back to the drawing board.

```
/* -*- Mode: ObjC; tab-width: 2; indent-tabs-mode: nil; c-basic-offset: 2; fill-column: 150 -*- */

#import <array>
#import <cassert>
#import <cstdio>

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import <CoreMidi/CoreMidi.h>

static constexpr bool DEBUG_MIDI2KBD(true);

static constexpr int BASE_KEYCODE(1000);

static CGEventSourceRef eventSource;

static std::array<unsigned char, 16*128> control;

static void NotifyProc(const MIDINotification *message, void *refCon)
{
}

static void sendKeyDownOrUpEvent(int character, int velocity, bool down) {
  CGEventRef event = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(eventSource, character + BASE_KEYCODE, down);

  // We send CJK Unified Ideographs characters
  constexpr int START = 0x4E00;
  assert(character >= 0 && character <= 20989);

  const UniChar string[1] = { (UniChar)(START + character) };

  CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString(event, 1, string);

  CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, event);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    MIDIClientRef midi_client;
    OSStatus status = MIDIClientCreate((__bridge CFStringRef)@"MIDI2Kbd", NotifyProc, nullptr, &midi_client);
    if (status != noErr) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error %d while setting up handlers\n", status);
      return 1;
    }

    eventSource = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStatePrivate);

    control.fill(0xFF);

    ItemCount number_sources = MIDIGetNumberOfSources();
    for (int i = 0; i < number_sources; i++) {
      MIDIEndpointRef source = MIDIGetSource(i);
      MIDIPortRef port;
      status = MIDIInputPortCreateWithProtocol(midi_client,
                                               (__bridge CFStringRef)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MIDI2Kbd input %d", i],
                                               kMIDIProtocol_1_0,
                                               &port,
                                               ^(const MIDIEventList *evtlist, void *srcConnRefCon) {
                                                 const MIDIEventPacket* packet = &evtlist->packet[0];

                                                 for (int i = 0; i < evtlist->numPackets; i++) {
                                                   // We expect just MIDI 1.0 packets.
                                                   // The words are in big-endian format.
                                                   assert(packet->wordCount == 1);

                                                   const unsigned char *bytes = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(&packet->words[0]);
                                                   assert(bytes[3] == 0x20);

                                                   if (DEBUG_MIDI2KBD)
                                                     printf("Event: %02X %02X %02X\n", bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);

                                                   switch ((bytes[2] & 0xF0) >> 4) {
                                                   case 0x9: // Note-On
                                                     assert(bytes[1] <= 0x7F);
                                                     sendKeyDownOrUpEvent((bytes[2] & 0x0F) * 128 + bytes[1], bytes[0], true);
                                                     break;

                                                   case 0x8: // Note-Off
                                                     assert(bytes[1] <= 0x7F);
                                                     sendKeyDownOrUpEvent((bytes[2] & 0x0F) * 128 + bytes[1], bytes[0], false);
                                                     break;

                                                   case 0xB: // Control Change
                                                     assert(bytes[1] <= 0x7F);
                                                     const int number = (bytes[2] & 0x0F) * 128 + bytes[1];
                                                     if (control.at(number) != 0xFF) {
                                                       int diff = bytes[0] - control.at(number);

                                                       // If it switches from 0 to 127 or back, we assume it is not really a continuous controller but
                                                       // a button.

                                                       if (diff == 127)
                                                         diff = 1;
                                                       else if (diff == -127)
                                                         diff = -1;

                                                       if (diff > 0) { 
                                                         for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
                                                           // Send keys indicating single-step control value increase
                                                           sendKeyDownOrUpEvent(16*128 + number * 2, diff, true);
                                                           sendKeyDownOrUpEvent(16*128 + number * 2, diff, false);
                                                         }
                                                       } else if (diff < 0) {
                                                         for (int i = 0; i < -diff; i++) {
                                                           // Send key indicating single-step control value decrease
                                                           sendKeyDownOrUpEvent(16*128 + number * 2 + 1, -diff, true);
                                                           sendKeyDownOrUpEvent(16*128 + number * 2 + 1, -diff, false);
                                                         }
                                                       }
                                                     }
                                                     control.at(number) = bytes[0];
                                                     break;
                                                   }

                                                   packet = MIDIEventPacketNext(packet);
                                                 }
                                               });
      if (status != noErr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %d while setting up port\n", status);
        return 1;
      }
      status = MIDIPortConnectSource(port, source, nullptr);
      if (status != noErr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %d while connecting port to source\n", status);
        return 1;
      }
    }
    CFRunLoopRun();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: (I built that code again, and checked what it does. It doesn't seem to work. Something has changed in the last years, or maybe I misremember whether the code used to work.)